# Is there a connection/memory limits for Apache Service while running cgi programs?

Tags: windows, perl, apache, process, windows-services

I'm trying to run hundreds of cgi programs (perl or other languages) concurrently on Apache 2.0/2.2/2.4. My test environment is Windows Server 2003 R2 with 1GB of RAM.

In the program, I use either an infinite loop or "$_ = < STDIN >" to keep each process alive. In the Apache configuration, I set all relative configurations large enough such as ThreadPerChild to 1000. Then I use JMeter to test 200 requests. When I run Apache in console application, it works fine and all 200 cgi processes are running. However, when I run Apache as a windows service, only 60-100 processes will run in concurrent. Others won't start unless I kill any running process. I don't what's causing this. Is there a connection/memory limits for Apache Service while running cgi programs? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`MaxClients` parameter in `httpd.conf` file sets the max limit of connections for apache server. 
The default connection limit is 256.

You can check it for your server by opening `httpd.conf` file and searching for MaxClients.

The default location of httpd.conf in linux is `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` .

On windows, the default location of conf file is `C:/Program Files/Apache Group/Apache/conf/httpd.conf`

It looks something like this.

```
# StartServers: number of server processes to start
# MinSpareServers: minimum number of server processes which are kept spare
# MaxSpareServers: maximum number of server processes which are kept spare
# ServerLimit: maximum value for MaxClients for the lifetime of the server
# MaxClients: maximum number of server processes allowed to start
# MaxRequestsPerChild: maximum number of requests a server process serves
<IfModule prefork.c>
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       256
MaxRequestsPerChild  4000
</IfModule>
```

You can set `MaxClients` value to whatever is needed and then restart the server to apply chages.

Comment: I tried all the configurations but none of them matters unfortunately. If it's only the conf issue it should work for both console app and service. I finally found out the reason yesterday. It's the windows desktop heap size that matters. Windows only assign 768kb heap size for each user service and somehow my process made it 100% usage and caused the fail of others. Thanks anyway!